# Using Array Formula with TEXTJOIN to separate with commas all non-blank fields in each row

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I am trying to create an array formula function that will pull the values of all fields in each row (between columns F and V) and separate them by ',' when not blank (from within only the row). The problem is that for row 2, it is inputting all values from all rows below rather than values from only each respective row. I am used to using vlookup array formulas that seem to work within columns.  Please see the formula below and the screenshot. Trying different range numbers or $ does not seem to provide the solutions.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,F2:V))
```

Formula in A2 is pulling all values from all rows of F through V and not 'arraying' the way desired

[image]

Comment: This way it wont work, you need to use either `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,F2:V2)` and fill down or else, use `BYROW()` --> `=BYROW(F2:V,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,x)))`

Comment: Wow. That is a great function. It works perfectly and continues to work with each new form entry on the sheet, the way I hoped array formula would. Thank you Mayukh!

Comment: Yes, do you want me to post an example in the answer

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, you should make it an answer